# How do the Trader books connect to the main Liaden storyline?

Tags: liaden

In the Liaden universe, has there yet been a connection made between the Trader books (Balance of Trade, Trade Secret) and the main line (Agent of Change, Fledgling, etc.)? I'm thinking it must be through the creation of Bechimo... but I don't recall reading anything directly on point. Have I missed something?

Comment: What do you mean by “connection”?

Comment: @jmoreno
By 'connection' I mean that the events/characters etc in one sent of books seemed to not have any relationship to the other books... nothing that happened in one set affected the other set, no common characters, etc.

Comment: Clans and contra are mentioned, as are fractions and auto-doc’s.  The Rabbit clan is mentioned in several books

Comment: Well, as to clans and cantra that is just background of the universe... Liadens, Terrans, ships, etc. I was looking for something a bit more specific. However I would be interested in knowing which books Rabbit clan is mentioned in. Do you read them much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe I asked this question just a little too early. The connection is beginning to be made in the newest book 'Trader's Leap', which just came out. The clan that was involved in the Trader books, turns out to have helped colonize a planet with Korval (mainline books), and the planet is the focus of the new book, with both clans coming together in a trading relationship.

Comment: Note that both can be found in the crystal soldier books

Comment: Both clans? I didn't realize that, it has been a while since I have read them. Still Trader's Leap seems a bit more specific of a connection, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Ixin is mentioned in I Dare:
"Deliberately, she sought out Korval's known allies and friends: Justus, Guayar, Ixin, Reptor, Mizel"

Mouse and Dragon: "Ixin, allow me to make you known to Aelliana Caylon Clan Mizel, Scholar and Pilot. Scholar Caylon, here is Lus Tin ven'Deelin, who has the honor to be Ixin"

Local Custom:  "To make matters even more confusing, it is assumed all persons of melant'i will have a firm grounding in Liaden heraldry, thus opening up vast possibilities for double-entendre and other pleasantries. "A hutch of bunnies," will indicate, en masse, the members of Clan Ixin, whose clan-sign is a stylized rabbit against a rising moon. Korval, whose distinctive Tree-and-Dragon is perhaps the most well-known clan-sign among non-Liadens, is given the dubious distinction of dragonhood and a murmured, "The Dragon has lifted a wing," should be taken as a word to the wise".

a *ven'Deelin* is quoted in Daughter of Dragons (found in The Tomorrow Log and Dragon Tide).

Korval is mentioned in both Balance of Trade "Korval Herself led the opposition, so the history texts tell us, and at last prevailed" and Trade Secret "On other fronts there was Korval, meddling as always".

Also, the Uncle is mentioned in Balance of Trade.

As for cantra, as it is named after Cantra, the founder of Korval, so I wouldn't consider it mere background content, it's not a dollar or a credit, it's the money minted using Korval's dies.

This shouldn't be taken as an exhaustive list, but yes, the books are clearly related, and not in the sense that Twilight and Anita Blake are set in the United States.  The clans at least have a history of interacting, although we don't see it happening on screen so to speak, until Trader's Leap.

Comment: Well... yes, but that's not quite what I mean. Take 'Fledgeling'. We follow the adventures of the young girl... and then suddenly in the middle of her overall story find out she is actually related to the Delm of Korval, and comes back to meet him, meets the turtles, etc. There is a difference between being in the same 'universe' (in the official sci fi sense) and being more related stories. I'm thinking that Trader's Leap is going to link together the characters in the Trader stories (possibly their great grandkids) and the main line of Korval.

Comment: And I am still wondering when we will figure out about the whole idea of Bechimo came from, and what was the crisis that stopped him from being crewed.

Comment: @VaughnOhlman: Bechimo is clearly an extension of the Uncle's work with fractin.  I would speculate that the crisis was just more intervention by the scout's, who at least as of BoT were not in favor of anything to do with them (or at least thought they were the only ones that should have them).

Comment: Well, that could well be. But with the amount of focus on it I would not be at all surprised if they wrote something, even if perhaps just a short story, covering those events.

Comment: OK, I just discovered another connection. When the Scout Ruling is made in Accepting the Lance it is mentioned that he was built in reaction to the secret then published document from the Trader series.